# poisson and distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

a pond has a rare diatom present that is randomly distributed in its surface water such that λ=3 cells/ml of surface water. if three 1.5 ml samples of surface water are independently taken, then what is the probability that exactly two of these three samples will contain four or more of these diatoms?

i tried solving this problem by using poisson and what i did was like this : pr(y=2)= 3^2/2 * e-3 and the result was .2243 but this answer was not in the options, any help ??

Answer (score 0):

For a single $1.5$ ml sample, the random number of cells present in that sample is Poisson with rate parameter $\lambda^* = 1.5 \lambda = 4.5$.  So the probability that a single sample contains four or more cells is $$p = \Pr[X_1 \ge 4] = 1 - \Pr[X_1 \le 3] = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^3 e^{-\lambda^*} \frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!}.$$  For three samples, the random number of samples $N$ that have four or more cells is binomially distributed with $n = 3$ and probability of success $p$ which we calculated above; i.e., $$\Pr[N = 2] = \binom{3}{2} p^2 (1-p)^{3-2}.$$

Comment: ok so i got it but why k=0 ??

Comment: Because there is a positive probability that in a single sample, you observed zero cells.